# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linker

I'm trying to install the ruby gem for curl (curb) on Ubuntu 10.10, but during the installation, I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
```

But curl is installed! apt-get install curl says I've got the newest version. There is no curl-dev either.

I'm getting these kinds of errors all the time, with curl, with libxml, with readline, and I have no idea what's going on. Something is wrong with my installation of Ubuntu, but I don't know what, I don't know where to look, I don't know what to google for, and I don't know how to fix it.

Help would be deeply appreciated.

EDIT: this is in my /usr/lib dir for libcurl:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      19 2011-02-18 23:15 libcurl-gnutls.so.3 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      23 2011-02-18 23:15 libcurl-gnutls.so.4 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4.2.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  339880 2010-06-23 09:07 libcurl-gnutls.so.4.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      12 2011-02-18 23:14 libcurl.so.3 -> libcurl.so.4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 2011-02-18 23:14 libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.2.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  360904 2010-06-23 09:07 libcurl.so.4.2.0
```

Comment: Does /usr/lib/libcurl.* exist? What about installing the libcurl3 package?

Comment: libcurl3 is installed, I've updated my question to show my /usr/lib dir.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need the libcurl3-dev package.
Curl is just the command line utility. The library is libcurl3, and it has a -dev package.
(It seems to be a virtual package in Maverick, redirecting to libcurl4-openssl-dev, but that should still work or the virtual package would not have been provided.) Indeed from your lib directory I can see that libcurl3 is merely a symbolic link to libcurl4. (libcurl3-dev may not be available in the future, so use libcurl4-openssl-dev directly).

Comment: Yay, just what I needed! So, check in /usr/lib and search for packages with correct version number and add -dev. Thank you very much!

Comment: I had a similar situation and just to clarify, all I had to do was install the libcurl4-openssl-dev as there is no libcurl3-dev package (12.04 x64)

Comment: This did it, thank you! Now I'm on to the next package conflict with this old software I'm trying to install. Thank you!